# How to insert sql data to HTML column after submit button was clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using PHP. I want to keep the user key-in input after submit button was clicked.

I found the following code example:

`<input type="date" id="bday" name="bday" size="30" 
    value="<?php echo isset($_POST['bday']) ? $_POST['bday'] : '' ?>" >`

But I  want to clear all the column of HTML and then insert the data from the database.

Now, I don't know how to insert back the data from database to HTML column.

Comment: Have you tried anything besides this copied example?

Comment: The answer to your question is: *PHP code connecting to a database and performing SELECT query > PHP code fetching results from SELECT query and parsing it into markup language > Browser displays the generated HTML*. But I'm sure that's not all you want so please clarify your question with the code you have tried so far and example of your goals.

Comment: Hi Aedix Rhinedale, my goal is display what had the user keyin after he/she clicked submit button in same page. I knew how to query the data from the database but I don't know how to insert back to the text column.